# Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, dapps

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

library CryptoSuite {
    function splitSignature(bytes memory sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (
            uint8 v,
            bytes32 r,
            bytes32 s
        )
    {
        require(sig.length == 65);

        assembly {
            //first 32bytes
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))

            //next 32bytes
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))

            //first 32bytes
            r := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }

        return (v, r, s);
    }

    function recoverSigner(bytes32 message, bytes memory sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (address)
    {
        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = splitSignature(sig);

        return ecrecover(message, v, r, s);
    }
}

contract ColdChain {
    enum Mode {
        ISSUER,
        PROVER,
        VERIFIER
    }
    struct Entity {
        address id;
        Mode mode;
        uint[] certificateIds;
    }

    enum Status {
        MANUFACTURED,
        DELIVERING_INTERNATIONAL,
        STORED,
        DELIVERING_LOCAL,
        DELIVERED
    }

    struct Certificate {
        uint id;
        Entity issuer;
        Entity prover;
        bytes signature;
        Status status;
    }

    struct VaccineBatch {
        uint id;
        string brand;
        address manufacturer;
        uint[] certificateIds;
    }

    uint public constant MAX_CERTITICATIONS = 2;

    uint[] public certificateIds;
    uint[] public vaccineBatchIds;

    mapping(uint => VaccineBatch) public vaccineBatches;
    mapping(uint => Certificate) public certificates;
    mapping(uint => Entity) public entities;

    event AddEntity(address entityId, string entityMode);
    event AddVaccineBatch(uint vaccineBatchId, address indexed manufacturer);
    event IssueCertificate(
        address indexed issuer,
        address indexed prover,
        uint certificateId
    );

    function addEntity(address _id, string memory _mode) public {
        Mode mode = unmarshalMode(_mode);
        uint[] memory _certificateIds = new uint[](MAX_CERTITICATIONS);
        Entity memory entity = Entity(_id, mode, _certificateIds);
        entities[_id] = entity;

        emit AddEntity(entity.id, _mode);
    }

    function unmarshalMode(string memory _mode)
        private
        pure
        returns (Mode mode)
    {
        bytes32 encodedMode = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_mode));
        bytes32 encodedMode0 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("ISSUER"));
        bytes32 encodedMode1 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("PROVER"));
        bytes32 encodedMode2 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("VERIFIER"));

        if (encodedMode == encodedMode0) {
            return Mode.ISSUER;
        } else if (encodedMode == encodedMode1) {
            return Mode.PROVER;
        } else if (encodedMode == encodedMode2) {
            return Mode.VERIFIER;
        }

        revert("recieved invalid entity mode");
    }

    function addVaccineBatch(string memory brand, address manufacturer)
        public
        returns (uint)
    {
        uint[] memory _certificateIds = new uint[](MAX_CERTITICATIONS);
        uint id = vaccineBatchIds.length;
        VaccineBatch memory batch = VaccineBatch(
            id,
            brand,
            manufacturer,
            _certificateIds
        );

        vaccineBatches[id] = batch;
        vaccineBatchIds.push(id);

        emit AddVaccineBatch(batch.id, batch.manufacturer);
        return id;
    }

    function issueCertificate(
        address _issuer,
        address _prover,
        string memory _status,
        uint vaccineBatchId,
        bytes memory signature
    ) public returns (uint) {
        Entity memory issuer = entities[_issuer];
        require(issuer.mode == Mode.ISSUER);

        Entity memory prover = entities[_prover];
        require(prover.mode == Mode.PROVER);

        Status status = unmarshalStatus(_status);

        uint id = certificateIds.length;
        Certificate memory certificate = Certificate(
            id,
            issuer,
            prover,
            signature,
            status
        );

        certificateIds.push(certificateIds.length);
        certificates[certificateIds.length - 1] = certificate;

        emit IssueCertificate(_issuer, _prover, certificateIds.length - 1);

        return certificateIds.length - 1;
    }

    function unmarshalStatus(string memory _status)
        private
        pure
        returns (Status status)
    {
        bytes32 encodedStatus = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_status));
        bytes32 encodedStatus0 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("MANUFACTURED"));
        bytes32 encodedStatus1 = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked("DELIVERING_INTERNATIONAL")
        );
        bytes32 encodedStatus2 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("STORED"));
        bytes32 encodedStatus3 = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked("DELIVERING_LOCAL")
        );
        bytes32 encodedStatus4 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("DELIVERED"));

        if (encodedStatus == encodedStatus0) {
            return Status.MANUFACTURED;
        } else if (encodedStatus == encodedStatus1) {
            return Status.DELIVERING_INTERNATIONAL;
        } else if (encodedStatus == encodedStatus2) {
            return Status.STORED;
        } else if (encodedStatus == encodedStatus3) {
            return Status.DELIVERING_LOCAL;
        } else if (encodedStatus == encodedStatus4) {
            return Status.DELIVERED;
        }

        revert("recieved invalid Certificate Status");
    }

    function isMatchingSignature(
        bytes32 message,
        uint id,
        address issuer
    ) public view returns (bool) {
        Certificate memory cert = certificates[id];
        require(cert.issuer.id == issuer);

        address recoveredSigner = CryptoSuite.recoverSigner(
            message,
            cert.signature
        );

        return recoveredSigner == cert.issuer.id;
    }
}
```

on this function am having an issue... :(

```
Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256.
```

issues are with these keywords **_issuer** and **_prover**
can anyone please help me???

Comment: Please, can you share all your smart contract code?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! The issue here is that you're using addresses (_issuer and _prover) somewhere where the an uint256 (a number) is expected. It could be anywhere where _issuer and _prover are used inside that function, but we can't tell without having a look at the  rest of your code, could you edit your question with the relevant info?

Comment: here you go. I've updated the question with a complete solidity code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue refers to querying a `entities` mapping. In details, when you declare a mapping in this way:

```
mapping(uint => Entity) public entities;
```

uint are the keys and Entity are the values.
Now, for querying this mapping you must put a uint value for retrieve Entity values related to it.
Example:

```
Entities memory _entity = entities[{uint}]; {uint} <- refers to key datatype!
```

All your issues in your smart contract refers to this misunderstanding.
I adjusted your smart contract in this way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

library CryptoSuite {
    function splitSignature(bytes memory sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (
            uint8 v,
            bytes32 r,
            bytes32 s
        )
    {
        require(sig.length == 65);

        assembly {
            //first 32bytes
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))

            //next 32bytes
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))

            //first 32bytes
            r := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }

        return (v, r, s);
    }

    function recoverSigner(bytes32 message, bytes memory sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (address)
    {
        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = splitSignature(sig);

        return ecrecover(message, v, r, s);
    }
}

contract ColdChain {
    enum Mode {
        ISSUER,
        PROVER,
        VERIFIER
    }
    struct Entity {
        address id;
        Mode mode;
        uint[] certificateIds;
    }

    enum Status {
        MANUFACTURED,
        DELIVERING_INTERNATIONAL,
        STORED,
        DELIVERING_LOCAL,
        DELIVERED
    }

    struct Certificate {
        uint id;
        Entity issuer;
        Entity prover;
        bytes signature;
        Status status;
    }

    struct VaccineBatch {
        uint id;
        string brand;
        address manufacturer;
        uint[] certificateIds;
    }

    uint public constant MAX_CERTITICATIONS = 2;

    uint[] public certificateIds;
    uint[] public vaccineBatchIds;

    mapping(uint => VaccineBatch) public vaccineBatches;
    mapping(uint => Certificate) public certificates;
    mapping(uint => Entity) public entities;
    // NOTE: I declared a variable that allows you to track the length of Entities in the mapping
    uint entitiesCount = 0; 

    event AddEntity(address entityId, string entityMode);
    event AddVaccineBatch(uint vaccineBatchId, address indexed manufacturer);
    event IssueCertificate(
        address indexed issuer,
        address indexed prover,
        uint certificateId
    );

    function addEntity(address _id, string memory _mode) public {
        Mode mode = unmarshalMode(_mode);
        uint[] memory _certificateIds = new uint[](MAX_CERTITICATIONS);
        Entity memory entity = Entity(_id, mode, _certificateIds);
        // NOTE: I changed _id with an uint value;
        entities[entitiesCount] = entity;

        emit AddEntity(entity.id, _mode);
    }

    function unmarshalMode(string memory _mode)
        private
        pure
        returns (Mode mode)
    {
        bytes32 encodedMode = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_mode));
        bytes32 encodedMode0 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("ISSUER"));
        bytes32 encodedMode1 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("PROVER"));
        bytes32 encodedMode2 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("VERIFIER"));

        if (encodedMode == encodedMode0) {
            return Mode.ISSUER;
        } else if (encodedMode == encodedMode1) {
            return Mode.PROVER;
        } else if (encodedMode == encodedMode2) {
            return Mode.VERIFIER;
        }

        revert("recieved invalid entity mode");
    }

    function addVaccineBatch(string memory brand, address manufacturer)
        public
        returns (uint)
    {
        uint[] memory _certificateIds = new uint[](MAX_CERTITICATIONS);
        uint id = vaccineBatchIds.length;
        VaccineBatch memory batch = VaccineBatch(
            id,
            brand,
            manufacturer,
            _certificateIds
        );

        vaccineBatches[id] = batch;
        vaccineBatchIds.push(id);

        emit AddVaccineBatch(batch.id, batch.manufacturer);
        return id;
    }

    function issueCertificate(
        uint _idIssuer,
        address _issuer,
        uint _idProver,
        address _prover,
        string memory _status,
        uint vaccineBatchId,
        bytes memory signature
    ) public returns (uint) {
        // NOTE: Entities mapping have uint datatype as KEY. For this reason if you want querying entities mapping 
        //       you must put a uint value  
        Entity memory issuer = entities[_idIssuer];
        require(issuer.mode == Mode.ISSUER);

        // NOTE: The same reasoning that I wrote in the previous comment (153-154)
        Entity memory prover = entities[_idProver];
        require(prover.mode == Mode.PROVER);

        Status status = unmarshalStatus(_status);

        uint id = certificateIds.length;
        Certificate memory certificate = Certificate(
            id,
            issuer,
            prover,
            signature,
            status
        );

        certificateIds.push(certificateIds.length);
        certificates[certificateIds.length - 1] = certificate;

        emit IssueCertificate(_issuer, _prover, certificateIds.length - 1);

        return certificateIds.length - 1;
    }

    function unmarshalStatus(string memory _status)
        private
        pure
        returns (Status status)
    {
        bytes32 encodedStatus = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_status));
        bytes32 encodedStatus0 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("MANUFACTURED"));
        bytes32 encodedStatus1 = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked("DELIVERING_INTERNATIONAL")
        );
        bytes32 encodedStatus2 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("STORED"));
        bytes32 encodedStatus3 = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked("DELIVERING_LOCAL")
        );
        bytes32 encodedStatus4 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("DELIVERED"));

        if (encodedStatus == encodedStatus0) {
            return Status.MANUFACTURED;
        } else if (encodedStatus == encodedStatus1) {
            return Status.DELIVERING_INTERNATIONAL;
        } else if (encodedStatus == encodedStatus2) {
            return Status.STORED;
        } else if (encodedStatus == encodedStatus3) {
            return Status.DELIVERING_LOCAL;
        } else if (encodedStatus == encodedStatus4) {
            return Status.DELIVERED;
        }

        revert("recieved invalid Certificate Status");
    }

    function isMatchingSignature(
        bytes32 message,
        uint id,
        address issuer
    ) public view returns (bool) {
        Certificate memory cert = certificates[id];
        require(cert.issuer.id == issuer);

        address recoveredSigner = CryptoSuite.recoverSigner(
            message,
            cert.signature
        );

        return recoveredSigner == cert.issuer.id;
    }
}
```